# Change background color of jface Dialog

Tags: java, swt, background-color, jface

I would like to change the default grey background of a jface.dialogs.Dialog derived Class. On [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/75569/) I read that this has to be done manually for each control.

So far, I was able to change all colors, except the color around the "OK" and "Cancel" button area. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `createButtonBar` method in your dialog:

```
@Override
protected Control createButtonBar(final Composite parent)
{
  final Composite barComp = (Composite)super.createButtonBar(parent);

  barComp.setBackground(your color);

  return barComp;
}
```

If you are using Eclipse 4.4 you can set the color to be something specified in the application CSS by using

```
WidgetElement.setCSSClass(barComp, "css-class-name");
```

instead of the `setBackground`